# Getting error when validating picture presence Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

This is my Gig model

```
class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "360x170>", :bigger => "650x459>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validate :image_size_validation

  def image_size_validation
    if image.size > 2.megabytes
      errors.add(:base, "Image should be less than 2MB")
    end
  end
end
```

Everything works great,i can not upload a picture greater than 2Mb as i wanted,and it gives a notice about that(written by me).

> **Question:** When I save the form(of a new product),without selecting any picture,it throws an error saying `undefined method >
>   for nil:NilClass`. Instead of just saying to the user,that he should
>   upload a picture,so the form can be saved.

Gig controller for create is this

```
def create
    @gig = current_user.gigs.build(gig_params)

    if @gig.save
      redirect_to @gig, notice: "Gig successfully created"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is clearly thrown by this line:

```
if image.size > 2.megabytes
```

obviously, if there isn't an image... it won't have a size.

How about you check for nil there:

```
def image_size_validation
  return if image.blank?
  if image.size > 2.megabytes
```

Comment: with your method the form gets saved without an image,when it should show a notice that "you can't go ahead till you add a picture",to the user.

Comment: A missing image should be caught by a presence-validation. (add something like: `validates :image, presence: true` if you need that) This is just making sure that the image-size-validation doesn't explode when you have  no image